# Adding new input with click function deletes previous input content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I have an "Add Guest" (Add input) button that when the user clicks it, a new input appears below it. My issue is if the user fills out an input and clicks the "Add Guest" button, what they typed into the first input is deleted.

Is there any way to keep the functionality I have, but to preserve what is in the inputs, while still adding new ones?

```js
$('#addGuest').click(function() {
  var count = $('.guestName').length;
  document.getElementById('guestWrap').innerHTML += '<div class="formField guestName" id="guestName' + (count + 1) + '"><label class="label">What is your guest\'s name?</label><input type="text" class="input" name="guest' + (count + 1) + '" id="guest' + (count + 1) + '"></div>';
  $('.guestName').fadeIn(400);
});
```

```css
.formField {
 margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.label {
 font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 line-height: 1.5em;
 margin: 20px 0;
 display: block;
}
.input {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: .9rem;
 display: block;
 width: 60%;
 padding: 15px 10px;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
 outline: none;
 -webkit-transition: 1s;transition: 1s;
}
#guestWrap {
 height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="guestWrap">
  <div class="formField guestName" id="guestName">
    <label class="label">What is your guest's name?</label>
    <input type="text" class="input" name="guest1" id="guest1">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="addGuest">
  <span class="guestIncrease">Add another guest</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you assign to the `innerHTML` of an element, the current elements get destroyed; the container is emptied, and only the original HTML string gets preserved. So, the current `value`s of any elements inside the container will be lost. Use `insertAdjacentHTML` instead, which does not dereference the existing elements:

```js
$('#addGuest').click(function() {
  var count = $('.guestName').length;
  document.getElementById('guestWrap').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div class="formField guestName" id="guestName' + (count + 1) + '"><label class="label">What is your guest\'s name?</label><input type="text" class="input" name="guest' + (count + 1) + '" id="guest' + (count + 1) + '"></div>');
  $('.guestName').fadeIn(400);
});
```

```css
.formField {
 margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.label {
 font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 line-height: 1.5em;
 margin: 20px 0;
 display: block;
}
.input {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: .9rem;
 display: block;
 width: 60%;
 padding: 15px 10px;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
 outline: none;
 -webkit-transition: 1s;transition: 1s;
}
#guestWrap {
 height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="guestWrap">
  <div class="formField guestName" id="guestName">
    <label class="label">What is your guest's name?</label>
    <input type="text" class="input" name="guest1" id="guest1">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="addGuest">
  <span class="guestIncrease">Add another guest</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect. I appreciate the help.